# updating the lastlogin column value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update the lastlogin column value .i wrote the code like this ,but column is nt updated .i wrote the some code in main.js for inserting query.here i didnt wrote any code for updating the lastlogin column value  in main.js.
for updating the lastlogin column i wrote the updatelogin function in the  dbfunc.php as below.

```
function updatelogin($lastlogin)
    {
         alert("hi");
        $query="UPDATE users set last_login='$lastlogin' where email='".$email."'";
         $queryresult= mysql_query($query);
         $count=mysql_num_rows($queryresult);
            if($count>0)
             {
                    return 1;
             }
            else
             {
                return 0;
            }    
        }   


    function register($details_arr)
       {
          $emailcheck=db_func::checkemail($details_arr['email']);
            if($emailcheck == 0){

         //print_r($details_arr);
         $regemail=$details_arr['email'];
       $regpwd=$details_arr['password'];
       $zip=$details_arr['zip'];
       $secqun=$details_arr['secqun'];
       $answer=$details_arr['answer'];
       $now=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
       $lastlogin=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());


       $query= "INSERT INTO users (email,md5pwd,zip,squestion,sanswer,member_since,last_login,last_ip) VALUES('".$regemail."','".$regpwd."','".$zip."','".$secqun."','".$answer."','".$now."','".$lastlogin."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')";
                 $queryresult=mysql_query($query);
                 echo mysql_error();
                if($queryresult)
                {
                    non_db_func::loginuser($email);
                    db_func::updatelogin($details_arr['lastlogin']);
                    return 1;
                    }

                else
                    return 0;
                    }
                     else{

                     return 2;    
                      }
```

can any one tell me ,why lastlogin column isnt updated in my db

Comment: try including `mysql_error()` on your query, and let's see what it has to say.

Comment: ....wait, you mention `main.js`, and you also mention `dbfunc.php`. Are you trying to do this query server-side or on the client? We need more information here. Also, read up on SQL injection and why it's a bad thing... you are massively vulnerable here.

Comment: i wrote the users table in mysql and inserted some data in the table.when next time i used the same email,pwd  in that time lastlogin column value is updated .im doing this in server side

Comment: can you type `echo $query` and let me know what you get?? ***This might solve your problem.***

Comment: i place echo $query,but it doesnt echo the query,i think problem in calling the function

Comment: @kanya : Can you provide full code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is that in function `updatelogin($lastlogin)` you have not defined what `$email` will hold.**

IF you echo your query after your query update statement (after `$query = UPDATE .....`)

```
echo $query
```

you will see what your problem is.

### Update 1

I think you should have something like this before `$query` statement
`$email=$details_arr['email'];`

### OR

pass `$email` value in function as `updatelogin($lastlogin, $email)`

Comment: i place echo $query,but it doesnt echo the query,i think problem in calling the function

Comment: @kanya : You didn't get my answer. The problem is that right now in function `updatelogin($lastlogin)`,  `$email` don't hold any value. Type echo "hi..."; before `$query` you will see hi... in output.

Comment: @kanya : Please see my updated answer and let me know if you have any question.

Comment: ya,i got it.i placed as u said,but it doesnt show any hi msg in o/p

Answer (score 0):

Either you have a mysql error you don't see or the email address you are trying to find does not exist.

Comment: it doesnt shows any error and i check the code with existing email address

Comment: change `db_func::updatelogin($details_arr['lastlogin']);` to `db_func::updatelogin($details_arr['lastlogin'], $details_arr['email']);` and `function updatelogin($lastlogin)` to `function updatelogin($lastlogin, $email)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass $email in function updatelogin

Because $email will not be accessible inside updatelogin

**And other thing you used $email instead of $regemail in your update query.**

Comment: function updatelogin($email)
    {
         alert("hi");
        $query="UPDATE users set last_login='$lastlogin' where email='".$regemail."'";
   now i changed like above,but its nt working

Comment: function updatelogin($lastlogin,$email) {  $query="UPDATE users set last_login='$lastlogin' where email='".$email."'"; mysql_query($query); }

Comment: you have to call updatelogin($details_arr['lastlogin'],$regemail);

Comment: ohhh. I found that there is no assignment for **$details_arr['lastlogin']** =>just replace it with $lastlogin variable i.e. call updatelogin($lastlogin,$regemail);

Answer (score 0):

**Can you Please Replcae your functions with below one and try again !**

```
function updatelogin($lastlogin,$email)
{
 $query="UPDATE users set last_login='".$lastlogin."' where email='".$email."'";
 $queryresult= mysql_query($query);
 $count=mysql_num_rows($queryresult);
    if($count>0)
     {
            return 1;
     }
    else
     {
        return 0;
    }    
}   


function register($details_arr)
{
  $emailcheck=db_func::checkemail($details_arr['email']);
    if($emailcheck == 0){

        //print_r($details_arr);
        $regemail=$details_arr['email'];
        $regpwd=$details_arr['password'];
        $zip=$details_arr['zip'];
        $secqun=$details_arr['secqun'];
        $answer=$details_arr['answer'];
        $now=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
        $lastlogin=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());


        $query= "INSERT INTO users (email,md5pwd,zip,squestion,sanswer,member_since,last_login,last_ip) VALUES('".$regemail."','".$regpwd."','".$zip."','".$secqun."','".$answer."','".$now."','".$lastlogin."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')";
        $queryresult=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        if($queryresult)
        {
            non_db_func::loginuser($email);
            db_func::updatelogin($lastlogin,$regemail);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
   }else{
        return 2;    
    }
}
```

Comment: in function `updatelogin($lastlogin)` can you tell me what data will variable `$email` have??

Comment: sorry i forgot ! Just Edited ! have a look ! Thanks

Comment: but OP don't have something like that... Also did you copied from ME??

Comment: @UditTrivedi : You can't put 2 answers. Better you merge all in One answer by writing Update 1 and so on...

Comment: @Fahim - I havn't copied from you . I have already answered this before you . Just check it out in answers. I just posted another answer with full code !

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in your code, first. `alert('hi)` is a javascript function. try `print_r('hi)` in the future, second. Your mysql is incorrectly formatted.

```
$query="UPDATE users set last_login='$lastlogin' where email='".$email."'";
```

You have escaped $email but not $lastlogin. Try this:

```
$query="UPDATE users set last_login='".$lastlogin."' where email='".$email."'";
```

Also as mentioned you need to pass $email into your function to use in mysql

Comment: i change the code as u said,but its not working and also i place the error message ,it doesnt show any erreor

Comment: I think you have a more fundamental error, as mentioned is this purely in PHP server side or are you doing something client side. Need to provide more information, surely you must be getting an error to screen?

Comment: im doing this one in server side,and i didnt get any error in the screen